# Add Multibinding converter as well as content to a button wpf

Tags: wpf, button, foreground, multibinding

In my wpf project I have:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Button Background="Transparent" Foreground="#E43D47" materialDesign:RippleAssist.IsDisabled="True" BorderBrush="Transparent">
            <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}">
                <Setter Property="Foreground">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <MultiBinding>
                            <MultiBinding.Converter>
                                <local:ProxyStatusForeground/>
                            </MultiBinding.Converter>
                            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="Column.Header"/>
                            <Binding/>
                            <Binding Path="HasChanges"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="⚫"/>
                        </ControlTemplate>

                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Button>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

I want to bind this button to my `multibinding.converter` as well as have ⚫ as the text so I can change it's foreground. If I do this ( I am doing it in a Datagrid Header ), whenever I add a row, it will show up with `System.Windows.Styles` instead of the ⚫. How would I be able to do this? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added the `Style` as the value for `Button.Content` (which will implicitly call `object.ToString()` on the `Style` instance, which will return the fully qualified name of the type):

```
<Button>
  <!-- this is setting the Content property -->
  Some Text
</Button>
```

which is equal to

```
<Button Content="Some Text" />
```

The `Style` must be a value of the `Button.Style` property:

```
<Button>
  <Button.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
      ...
    </Style>
  </Button.Style>
</Button>
```